# SQL Server, Joomla and IIS7

Tags: mysql, sql-server, iis-7, joomla

Is there a SQL Server Provider for Joomla? I know that there is a SQL Server Client for PHP in beta and I wonder whether it would be hard to change the database provider to point to SQL Server instead of MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=142051) thread (specifically [this](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1703283#p1703283) post) in the official Joomla forum some queries in the Joomla source code are MySQL specific and do not work on Microsoft SQL Server.

> It's Joomla itself, some queries in the code are specific for Mysql. Making Joomla work for MSSQL at the moment consists of looking through all queries, checking which ones are Mysql specific and change them to MSSQL or generic ANSI SQL specific.

Comment: This answer is old and somewhat outdated.  There has been some work to produce a more DB-independent joomla.  Some have called it "multidb joomla".  It's not official yet, but it basically works.