# Migrating from Joomla 2.5 MySQL to SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, joomla

I have created Joomla 2.5 website which runs great but my client requests from me to change MySQL db with SQL Server. I am trying to find solution via Google search but still no luck.

Is there any painless way to achieve this (perhaps some step by step tutorial) and what are the possible disadvantages of migrating to SQL Server?

Any help is appreciated and many thanks in advance!
Adi

Comment: Does the version meet the minimum requirements for MS SQL support in Joomla? If so you should in theory be able to change the database information in the configuration.php and Joomla will run. You might be able to use JDatabase to migrate the data.

Comment: Hello Elin, yes it definetely meets requirements. Please tell me did you tried anything similar based on your experince and what are the possible disadvantages of Joomla + MS SQL combination?

Comment: Mainly it's not as commonly used so there are lots more undiscovered bugs, though if you run into anything check the Joomla issue tracker.

Comment: Basically 2.5 does not support ms sql but you can get support by using some of the code that hoodooku did which I think is available on joomlacode.

Answer (score 0):

By default Joomla doesn't support MS SQL databases. But there are possible workarounds, you can check this answer:
[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042351/can-i-use-ms-sql-server-as-the-backing-database-for-joomla)
But it's not a good idea, because any system update would destroy your changes.

Comment: It supports it for 3.x but not officially for 2.5.